Displaying message on terminated session device and redirect to community login page
We have a login flow in our community. If a second user logs in with a user that is already logged in, it terminates the old session and continues with the new one.
There is no issue with terminating the session, but even when the session is no longer active, the first user does not know that the session has been terminated. If they change the page, they are directed to the login page (which is working as expected). However, if they remain on the same page and try to use any function on that page, every function throws a VF Exception. This appears to be a bug to our customers.
Do you know of any solution for this issue? At the very least, I need to refresh the page so that they can be automatically redirected to the login screen.I have tried the browser alert function but it just displays message and not refreshing the page.
